# How to pilot a 3rd party javascript library running on a custom HTML element from an Angular 6 component?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular6

My goal is to encapsulate an existing javascript Video player as a standalone Angular 6 module.

The player gets embedded into a web page by a custom HTML element (known henceforth as *<media-player>*) that takes in some parameter attributes.
Its logic is located in a single proprietary (minified) Javascript file, that provides the methods (play/stop, etc.) that can be applied to the DOM reference of that HTML element. Example :

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/media-player.js"></script>
   </head>
    <body>
        <media-player id="my_player" media='{"url":"http://example.com"}' />
    </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
var player = document.getElementById('my_player');
player.play();
player.stop();
```

I'm assuming that the library works by searching for that particular element in the DOM once the page is loaded, and rendering a bunch of video-playing stuff in its place, with the JS API being implemented as a collection of extension methods on that element.

My issue originates from the lack of exposition of any direct method or variable.
Most online solutions refer to exposing some known methods or variables of the underlying library via a `declare var MyLibrary: any;` statement.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but this is not possible in this case, because there's no such object available for declaration, and the library is pretty much a black box from my perspective.
Reverse engineering the library is not an option at this stage.

Comment: Is there any chance you can name the library? It shouldn't be too hard, it's just about wrapping things correctly and doing a clever usage of `@ViewChild` and `nativeElement`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not open/public. It is made by a local company specialized in video playout solutions. I will start looking into the keywords you mentioned, seeing as I currently have little idea to what they represent. Thank you.

Comment: Usually, those library has some kind of init or whatever. The cleverest approach you can probably follow is: 1) Create a component. 2) Create the relevant HTML. 3) Create the custom library instance in NgOnInit. 4) Expose the native element through `#` and `@ViewChild`. 5) Access the native element. 6) Profit.